# Add header interceptor after login - Retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm having an issue from some days, I know how to set a header interceptor, the thing is, how do I set a header interceptor only after the login because my flow is :

Login without auth just user and password

Then server returns the Bearer token

How do I set the header authentication automatically instead of adding it manually on each call of retrofit? Is there any way?
Do I have to use the same instance of Retrofit?

Comment: Generally you'd perform a login to to get your token prior to making a service call, and that would be via some sort of an interceptor. Perhaps it would be a bit more obvious if you include an example code to explain better what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making your custom interceptor, below is the code

```
 class AuthorizationInterceptor(var context: Context) : Interceptor {

     override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request: Request = chain.request()
        val sessionId = "Your Session Id"

        if (tempSessionId != null) {
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $tempSessionId").build()
        }
       return chain.proceed(request)
     }
}
```

And then add this Interceptor by following way

```
class RetrofitInstance(var context: Context) {

    private val BASE_URL = APIVersionConstants.BASE_URL


    private val builder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(makeOkHttpClient()) 


    private fun makeOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(AuthorizationInterceptor(context)) //<----HERE
            .build()
    }

    private val retrofit = builder.build()

    fun <T> buildService(serviceType: Class<T>): T {
        return retrofit.create(serviceType)
    }


}
```

It's done

Comment: Thanks for answering, the thing is the first retrofit call, I do not have access Token it comes when I do the Login, so that's why if I create the interceptor I do not have the token yet (for the first call), also what is tempSessionId?

Comment: TempSessionId is your access token which is coming from Shared Preferences... I have put condition like if it is null so it will not add... So before login it will not add.. After login you can save it into shared preferences and can get back into interceptor from Shared Preferences..

Comment: If it feels good to you, you can up vote and approve answer so, it will helpful for others as well